# How do I test the functionality whilst awaiting response using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component that I am testing using Jest. The innards component looks something like this:

```
const [words, setWords] = useState(['Word','Another']);

const handleSelection = async selection => {
    setWords([]);
    const { response } = await apiCall(selection);
    setWords(response.split(' '));
};

return (
   <div>
     {words.map(word => (
         <p 
            onClick={() => handleSelection(word)} 
            data-testid='words'
         >
           {word}
         </p>
     )}
   </div>
)
```

How do I test that words array will be empty whilst awaiting the api response? FYI I have setTimeouts of 1500ms elsewhere in the component. They get rendered on initial load in a useEffect hook.

Currently I have this:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        apiCall.mockImplementation(() => ({ response: 'This is the response' }));
    });


    it("words disappear whilst awaiting api response", async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        const { getAllByTestId, queryAllByTestId } = render(<Comp />);

        const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null });
        
        act(() => {
            jest.runAllTimers();
        });

        await act(async () => {
            await user.click(getAllByTestId('words')[0])
        });
        expect(getAllByTestId('words')).toHaveLength(0);
        
        jest.useRealTimers();
    });
```

This is the fail reason, which obviously I understand why this is the result:

```
Expected length: 0
Received length: 4
Received array:  [<p data-testid='words'>This</p>,<p data-testid='words'>is</p>,<p data-testid='words'>the</p>,<p data-testid='words'>response</p>]
```

How would I get it to pause whilst awaiting? I tried setting the mockImplementation to a setTimeout which returned the response, and then advancing timers to a point where the response would not have returned within the timeout yet, but this didn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can wrap your assertion expect(queryAllByTestId('words')).toHaveLength(0); in waitFor

Comment: I think theres something I'm missing because I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: You should be able to use a `findBy` query instead of calling `act`. https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries See also https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider is to have a setup like this:

```
it("your test", (done) => {
    // setup-related code

    setTimeout(() => {
        // code where you do the checking

        // callback to indicate that your test has finished.
        done();
    }, 1500);
});
```

If you could somehow await the process, that would be even better, but if you don't find a way to do that, this could do the trick.